# Find a Class in Visual Studio's generated Class Diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I want to understand the class relationship in our project, so I generated the class diagram of the solution that we have from Visual Studio 2012.

But our solution consist of hundreds+ of classes, the generated diagram is really pretty huge.

I wonder if there is a Search function I can find the class and locates it insides the Class Diagram using a class name?

I tried Ctrl+F but it seems only search for the other files...  I tried to export to other format so I can search into it, but it seems only support export into image.

Does the Search function even exists?